# Job Restrictions Plugin, Regular Expression(Job Name)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops

Target: Restrict all jobs from my node, except jobs that include "it_test_patch" part in job name.

Solutions that doesn't work for me:
`/^.*(it_test_patch)/` (and any sort of regexp, all regular expressions I checked in regexp generators)

[Variant 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVzSQ.png)

[Variant 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xbjw.png)

[Variant 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrYZF.png)

[Variant 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbvL9.png)

Comment: I am using last version of this plugin.

Comment: It seems that you need to match files without "it_test_patch" in name, try `/^(?!.*(it_test_patch)).*/`